# Javascript Variable Hoisting not Behaving as Expected in Scratchpad

Tags: javascript, scope, hoisting, scratchpad

I am following the Mozilla developers Javascript tutorial and there is a segment on variable hosting. The tutorial at one point mentions using Firefox's Scratchpad in order to edit javascript to quickly save and see code run.

The code i used (copy paste from tutorial) is:

```
/**
 * Example 1
 */
console.log(x === undefined); // true
var x = 3;

/**
 * Example 2
 */
// will return a value of undefined
var myvar = 'my value';

(function() {
  console.log(myvar); // undefined
  var myvar = 'local value';
})();
```

However `console.log(x === undefined)` returns `false`. And if I run `console.log(x);` instead it actually returns `3`. `console.log(myvar);` below returns undefined as expected.

I'm confused as what is supposed to be happening here, is the documentation possibly incorrect/outdated or does Scratchpad interpret this code differently from standard JavaScript, and if so why? I tried to run in a .js file and I get results as expected.

Comment: The console will implicitly use the current page's global scope (the `window`), so once you've defined `x` it stays defined. You could wrap all that code in a big immediately-executed function to make sure you start off with a clean context.

Comment: Did you maybe run the example code twice? Then `x` would have already been initialised with `3` on the second (and all subsequent) runs.

Comment: But why would re-running the code save the previous variable. Should the 'memory' not get cleared as .js script is running again? Or does this only occur during a complete refresh of the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Immediate function, you **re**declared the `myvar` variable in:

```
(function() {
  console.log(myvar); // undefined
  var myvar = 'local value';
})();
```

So the global `myvar` variable from the `window` scope will be hoisted that's why it returns `undefined` in `console.log(myvar);`.

In the other hand if you replace it with `console.log(x);`, it will print `3` because you haven't redeclared the `x` variable.

**Your problem:**

And for the first `console.log(x === undefined);` statement, it will return `false` only if you **re**execute it, so maybe in your case it was executed twice.